# Enable/disable add-in button programmatically (for Microsoft VSTO C# add-in)

Tags: c#, user-controls, vsto, office-addins

I am making a PowerPoint add-in. Some of the buttons should only be enabled when the user selects a table, since the functions only apply to tables. I can't get this to work. It seems like it all works and I can set button.Enabled = true but the UI is not getting updated. What can I do?

Here is a simplified version of the code. I removed the logic "if selection == table, enable. Else, disable" for simplicity. For now, I just want to get the UI to update

**Class ThisAddIn.cs**

```
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
namespace PPT_CS_ADDIN
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private UserControl1 myUserControl;
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            myUserControl = new UserControl1();
            this.Application.WindowSelectionChange += Application_WindowSelectionChange;
        }
        private void Application_WindowSelectionChange(PowerPoint.Selection Sel)
        {
            myUserControl.UpdateButtonStates(Sel);
        }
        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }       
    }
}
```

**Class UserControl1.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
namespace PPT_CS_ADDIN
{
    public partial class UserControl1
    {
        
        private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public void UpdateButtonStates(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Selection selection)
        {
            button11.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Class UserControl1.Designer.cs**

```
namespace PPT_CS_ADDIN
{
    partial class UserControl1 : Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonBase
    {

        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        public UserControl1()
            : base(Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory())
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.tab1 = this.Factory.CreateRibbonTab();
            this.group3 = this.Factory.CreateRibbonGroup();
            this.button11 = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
            this.button13 = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
            this.tab1.SuspendLayout();
            this.group3.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // tab1
            this.tab1.ControlId.ControlIdType = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlIdType.Office;
            this.tab1.Groups.Add(this.group3);
            this.tab1.Label = "TabAddIns";
            this.tab1.Name = "tab1";
            // group3
            this.group3.Items.Add(this.button11);
            this.group3.Items.Add(this.button13);
            this.group3.Label = "Table";
            this.group3.Name = "group3";
            // button11
            this.button11.Label = "Button";
            this.button11.Name = "button11";
            // UserControl1
            this.Name = "UserControl1";
            this.RibbonType = "Microsoft.PowerPoint.Presentation";
            this.Tabs.Add(this.tab1);
            this.Load += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonUIEventHandler(this.UserControl1_Load);
            this.tab1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tab1.PerformLayout();
            this.group3.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.group3.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
        internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonTab tab1;
        internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonGroup group3;
        internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton button11;
        internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonButton button13;
    }

    partial class ThisRibbonCollection
    {
        internal UserControl1 UserControl1
        {
            get { return this.GetRibbon<UserControl1>(); }
        }
    }
}
```

I have debugged the entire process, it seems like the problem is that button11 is not refreshed. I tried the methods Invalidate, ResumeLayout, SuspendLayout, PerformDynamicLayout, Refresh, on the button and the UserControl but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example project in [GitHub here](https://github.com/Excel-projects/Script-Help)

C# code

You can use the call

```
    ribbon.InvalidateControl(control.Id);
```

and the function

```
    public bool GetEnabledProcedureName(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (control.Id)
            {
                case "btnYourButton":
                case "btnCleanData":
                case "btnZeroToNull":
                case "btnFormatDateColumns":
                case "btnFormatTimeColumns":
                case "btnClearInteriorColor":
                case "btnAddScriptColumn":
                    return ErrorHandler.IsEnabled(false);
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorHandler.DisplayMessage(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

XML for ribbon

```
                <button id="btnYourButton"
                        label="Your Button Label"
                        onAction="OnActionProcedureName"
                        getEnabled="GetEnabledProcedureName"
                        imageMso="ImageReferenceNameHere"
                        size="normal"
                        screentip="Your Screen Tip"
                        supertip="Your super tip"
                        keytip="CVC"/>
```

Comment: I don't have an XML file. I have a designer.cs file that initializes the ribbon and sets values for label, screentip, etc. Can I implement the equivalent of getEnabled=GetEnabledProcedureName on the designer.cs file?

Comment: I'll see if I can setup an example